How to convert an HTML hyperlink inside a cell to an Excel hyperlink?
In Excel 365 (version 2407), I have a row of HTML hyperlinks in plain text format. Each cell in that row includes something like:
<a href="https://www.example.com/products/matters/m_document_edit.php?id=1026574&docid=10213208">Display text</a>
I would like to change these HTML hyperlinks to clickable Excel hyperlinks.
I tried the following formula (the HTML hyperlink is in cell D2) but received a #VALUE! error.
=HYPERLINK(MID(D2, FIND("href='", D2) + 6, FIND("'>", D2) - FIND("href='", D2) - 6), MID(D2, FIND(">", D2) + 1, FIND("</a>", D2) - FIND(">", D2) - 1))
What am I doing wrong?

@Harun24hr Version 2407 (part of Office 365)

rotabor's comment has the correct answer:
=HYPERLINK(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,"href="""),""">"),TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,""">"),"</a>"))
This formula preserves the original display text of the link.

Try the following formula-
=HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,"href="),">"),CHAR(34),""),"Click Here")



SUBSTITUTE looks like extra here. Just include the double-quotes in strings to search like "href=""".

There is also a trailing double quote before >.

It would be nice also to display the text to display form HTML (Display text) instead of "Click Here".

This formula gets rid of the link's display text and replaces it with "click here'. I'd like to keep each link's original display text.

I intentionally didn't repeat the way how to include the double-quote in a string. Evidently, """>"

@DaveGa =HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,"href="),">"),CHAR(34),""),"Display Text").

It's not a good idea.

@rotabor Thanks for pointing it. =TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,"href="""),""">") this is fine. Full formula will be =HYPERLINK(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,"href="""),""">"),"Display Text").

=HYPERLINK(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,"href="""),""">"),TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(D2,""">"),"</a>"))

@rotabor You got it right!
